# Routing on button click in angular 5

Tags: angular, routes, angular5

I need to route to a home component when the user clicks a button. I know how to do that using: `<a href=””>`, but not using: `routerLink`. Is there any way to do that using a `button` `click` event?

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link-edit" [routerLink]="['']">home</a>
```

The code above is how I use an `<a href="">` tag to route.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, `routerLink` works on both anchor tags and button tags. You can do this:

```html
<button class="nav-item nav-link-edit" [routerLink]="['']">home</button >
```

Comment: thanks. it working. is there any way to do something before route to the next page?

Comment: If you are talking about doing something in the current component before leaving you will need to ditch `routerLink` and just navigate in your component. You can bind to the `click` method on the button and have it call the method in your component that runs your logic and then routes. If you are talking about running some code before a route resolves you will need to look into a [Resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

Comment: Works on Angular 9 as well.

Answer (score 3):

routerLink will be working properly.

**app.component.html**:

```
<button class="nav-item nav-link-edit" [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</button >
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: I can't see any different between your answer and Teddy's one. but I appreciate your help  try to give alternative solution if you try to answer an answered question. Don't be discourage.